# How to override django edit_inline/tabular.html for only 1 app?

Tags: django-admin, django-templates

I can override `edit_inline/tabular.html` if I save it in my overall template directory (for example `mysite/templates/admin/edit_inline/tabular.html`), but when I try to save it with other admin template, like `change_form.html` (in `mysite/myapp/templates/admin/myapp/mymodel/change_form.html`, it doesn't works.

Answer (score 12):

I come across this thread which is a bit old, in fact for the inline model you need to explicitly set your new template in your admin.py like below :

```
class ModelInlineAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Product
    template = "admin/products/product/edit_inline/stacked.html"
```

check this <s>http://blog.ruedaminute.com/2011/05/django-journal-override-a-django-admin-template-inline-or-otherwise/</s>

Comment: Thank you for the answer, please mind that the link provided is no longer active.

Answer (score 5):

[The documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.template) hints that inlines can have a `template` attribute. Try setting that to `admin/myapp/mymodel/edit_inline/tabular.html` and create the corresponding template file in the `templates` directory of `myapp`.

Answer (score 0):

The form is like this:

templates/admin/app_name/override.html

For you change_form.html example, it should be like this:

mysite/templates/admin/myapp/change_form.html

See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates for more.

Comment: This doesn't answer about inlines, only regular admin pages.